# qmldir: plugin cannot be loaded for module "myplugin": module namespace QuickQanava

Tags: qt

I am using qml with QuickQanava for loading a plugin and I am getting error while loading the 'QuickQanava' plugin from my QML file in windows and I have built my application using Visual Studio.

I have Set QML2_IMPORT_PATH to the plugin directories and have also copied the 'quickqanavaplugin.dll' into the application.exe folder

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks